# Find the index of similiar elements in lists

Tags: python

I have these two lists:

---

```
list_1 = ['less', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more']

list_2 = ['less', 'less', 'less', 'more', 'less', 'less', 'more', 'less']
```

---

I want to find the index in list_1 if the corresponding element in the other list is the same.
For example `list_1[0] = list_2[0]` , 0 would be the first element of the index list I am looking for but `list_1[1] != list_2[1]`, so 1 would not be in my list

Comment: do two list have same size?

Comment: yes they do!...

Comment: actually index in list_1 or in list_2 would be the same.

Comment: First your question and your code, you need have write your code and your try and ask and say this is your problem and your error

Comment: you can read this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `zip` them, then check two by two and with `enumerate` save index like below. *(as I ask and you say two list have same size)*

Try this:

```
>>> list_1 = ['less', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more', 'more']
>>> list_2 = ['less', 'less', 'less', 'more', 'less', 'less', 'more', 'less']
>>> [idx for idx, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(list_1, list_2)) if a==b]
[0, 3, 6]

# for more details
>>> list(zip(list_1, list_2))
[('less', 'less'),
 ('more', 'less'),
 ('more', 'less'),
 ('more', 'more'),
 ('more', 'less'),
 ('more', 'less'),
 ('more', 'more'),
 ('more', 'less')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
[i for i in range(len(list_1)) if list_1[i]==list_2[i]]
```

if the lists are of the same length

---

out:

```
[0, 3, 6]
```